# NodeJS query data from a Azure SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, node.js

So I have been trying to get a connection working with Node to a Azure hosted SQL Server database.

When I try to run the code it says that it established a connection with the database. Then it tries to query something from it. But I get his error:

[image]

```
const config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  options: { encrypt: true }
};

app.get('/dbtest', async (req, res) => {

    var conn = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config);

    conn.connect()
   // Successfull connection
    .then(function () {

      // Create request instance, passing in connection instance
      var req = new mssql.Request(conn);

      // Call mssql's query method passing in params
      req.query("SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]")
        .then(function (recordset) {
          console.log(recordset);
          conn.close();
        })
        // Handle sql statement execution errors
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          conn.close();
        })

    })
    // Handle connection errors
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      conn.close();
    });
```

I use the npm package `mssql` for this, but I've also tried using the `tedious` package (with its own syntax) but neither of them seems to be able to give me some correct results.

All the help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is "[SalesLT].[Customer]"?

Comment: It is the schema and table name

Comment: I see. Can you try using this format in the query - [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]?

Comment: Then I would get this respone: Reference to database and/or server name in 'ads.SalesLT.Customer' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Crazy question but is SalesLT your DB name and not schema. Are you trying to access SomeDatabase.SalesLT.Customer or SalesLT.SomeSchema.Customer